# Set Recipient in MS Outlook Addin

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am attempting to add a `recipient` dynamically to the `requiredAttendees` for an Outlook appointment

```
var arr = [{emailAddress: 'test@example.com', displayName: 'Test Name'}]
Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees.addAsync(arr)

(also fails with arr = ['test@example.com'])
```

and it is throwing an error

```
Sys.ArgumentException: Sys.ArgumentException: 
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

How might that be accomplished?

Cf. [docs which I am following](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item.md#requiredattendees-arrayemailaddressdetailsrecipients)

Cf. [Radio-silence Github issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/370)

---

### UPDATE SCREEN SHOTS

[image: Array.isInstanceOfType before Throw]

#### PRE-THROW

- You can notice that `n` is correctly defined as an array with 1 value (right panel)
- Checking the same array as `arr` from the console evaluates to `true`

---

[image: Outlook Recipients Array Throw Error]

#### Throw

- The script is `throwing` on evaluation (as indicated by the light green highlight)

Comment: Verified on latest version and working fine. Could you please update to latest verson and try ?

Comment: I added screenshots to demonstrate the issue. I am able to set manually from the console, so the function exists and presumably is not a versioning issue (though I updated my cdn reference as a check)

Comment: Updated Mac Outlook client to `16.22` (latest available client via Outlook-check-for-updates) and the issue persists. Further, I am able to use other `Office` apis, so the library is fully loaded at the time of execution

Answer (score 1):

To get dynamic URL params, I am loading an iframe `onInit` when Office is done initializing.

Though the rest of the API is available to the loaded iframe when passed in, there is something inherent to this particular piece of the API that must be dependent on `window`.

Moving the API call outside of the iframe fixes the issue and causes it to work as expected.